# How to prove the existence of the following equation?

Tags: physics, vector-analysis

I learned electrodynamics.
According to the vector potential determination, 
$$
\mathbf B = [\nabla \times \mathbf A ],
$$
Coulomb gauge,
$$
\nabla \mathbf A = 0,
$$
and one of Maxwell's equations,
$$
[\nabla \times \mathbf B ] = \frac{1}{c}4\pi \mathbf j,
$$

I can assume, that

$$
[\nabla \times \mathbf B ] = \nabla (\nabla \mathbf A) - \Delta \mathbf A = -\Delta \mathbf A = \frac{1}{c}4 \pi \mathbf j.
$$
How to prove that the one of the solutions of this equation is solution like newtonian potential,
$$
\mathbf A = \frac{1}{c}\int \limits_{V} \frac{\mathbf j (r) d^{3}\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_{0}|}?
$$

Comment: The usual procedure is to find the solution of $\Delta A(r) = \delta(r)$ (the green function of the equation) and to make a convolution with the inhomogeneous part. In this case it seems that the green function in $1/|r|$.

Comment: I don't know about the Green function, because I don't study math on this level. Can you explain if it won't be hard?

Comment: It is based on Fourier transform, do you know it?

Comment: Yes, I know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping the part about the Green's function, you should apply Fourier transformation on your equation

$$-\Delta \mathbf A = \frac{1}{c}4 \pi \mathbf j.$$

to change it into

$$k^2 \tilde{\mathbf{A}} = \frac{1}{c}4 \pi \tilde{\mathbf{j}}$$

or

$$\tilde{\mathbf{A}} = \frac{1}{c}4 \pi \tilde{\mathbf{j}}\cdot\frac{1}{k^2}$$

The left hand side is a product, so the inverse Fourier transform will be a convolution. The inverse Fourier transform of $1/k^2$ is $1/|r|$ in 3D, as you can see in [formula 502](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Formulas_for_general_n-dimensional_functions). Therefore one gets

$$\mathbf A = \frac{1}{c}\int \limits_{V} \frac{\mathbf j (r) d^{3}\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r_{0}|} \; .$$

Comment: From a mathematician's viewpoint, a cleaner approach would be to insert $\mathbf{A}$ into the equations and check. Fourier analysis requires assumptions that might be heavier than those for being a pointwise solution.

Comment: Sure, but I used Fourier analysis precisely because the OP knows it.

Comment: I understand. But also direct differentiation might be a good exercise.